# insert value from hex datetime sql to datetime MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, datetime

I have this line of code from a sql DDBB export (... are other fields and values):

```sql
INSERT INTO 'table' (..., created_at, ..) VALUES (..., CAST(0x03A076C802DF3F0B00 AS datetime), ...);
```

as far I know works on SQL.

but to migrate this line to a .sql file for Mysql DDBB I need to translate this to a datetime Mysql. As far I know datetime hex values on sql y 16 digits, 8 for date from 1970 and 8 for seg from 00:00. but this have 18 digits I dont kwon what is this about.

I have tried convert, split the hex number, but it retrieves NULL.
And I cant know the hex true datetime value by now.

Comment: Can;t you just export the converted datetime and import in MySQL?

Comment: This value doesn't convert to a date in my SQL test server (2017). So as far as *I* know it does not work at all and won't convert to MySQL.

Comment: @SalmanA i would like, but right now I have no access to that DDBB.

Comment: @JacobH yeah i was suspecting that but then why this hex value, i mean it has 2 extras digits, and who gave me this code said the export file is correct. thanx for checking BTW

Comment: It is impossible to help without knowing what date 0x03A076C802DF3F0B00 corresponds to, and is it is even valid?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a datetime2 value. Datetime2 stores its data byte-reversed (known as little-endian). First byte represents precision. Last 3 byte represent date part, after last 3 byte until precision part represent time part. Because of precision is lower than three, this value consists of 7 bytes and precision. Therefore last two digits are added when converting binary.

You can find detailed explanation in below links.

[learn.microsoft.com - datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

[bornsql.ca - datetime2](https://bornsql.ca/blog/dates-times-sql-server-datetime2/)

```
-- 0x03 A0 76 C8 02 DF 3F 0B 00

-- Date Part : 0B 3F DF
-- Time Part : 02 C8 76 A0
-- Precision : 03

set @hexdate = '0x03A076C802DF3F0B00';
set @precision = 3;
set @days = CONV(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@hexdate, 17, 2),
                        SUBSTRING(@hexdate, 15, 2),
                        SUBSTRING(@hexdate, 13, 2)), 16, 10);

set @seconds = CONV(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@hexdate, 11, 2),
                           SUBSTRING(@hexdate, 9, 2),
                           SUBSTRING(@hexdate, 7, 2),
                           SUBSTRING(@hexdate, 5, 2)), 16, 10) / POWER(10, @precision);

SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD('0001-01-01', INTERVAL @days DAY), INTERVAL @seconds SECOND);


Result: 2019-07-08 12:58:12
```

Comment: It's a lot easier to use an ISO8601 date literal. It's unambiguous and takes only a single line. There's no valid reason to export a date as a hex, only to try to convert it back to a date

Comment: Yes, you are right. But sometimes we have no control over exporting data. That is why we need this.